# How do I add a device to iCloud that was accidentally deleted?

Tags: icloud, apple-id

I got some new AirPods. I went to delete the old ones using https://appleId.apple.com.

I thought I was deleting my old AirPods but it ended up removing my new AirPods (I think there is a bug with their website). I've re-paired the airpods, but they don't show up as one of my devices. They still show up in findMy (along with my other removed devices). iCloud features such as the automatic handoff are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Unpair the AirPods in Bluetooth settings, then re-pair them.

Comment: This added the device back to FindMy, and I'm able to modify the AirPod's settings, but it does not show up under my devices in iCloud.

Comment: @rob did it also not fix the handoff/synced pairing?

Comment: I think handoff is working ok - though I think had to pair my phones with the new device. It's still not showing up under my devices in iCloud.